# GWT event prevent default not working in Java

Tags: java, events, gwt

I'm new to GWT and I need to get a right click working. The doco I've read suggests that I need to override the onBrowserEvent() method. I'm just experimenting at this stage. the event is processed and my pop-up appears. However, as soon as I close the pop-up, the usual browser drop down menu appears (with options like "Bookmark this page" and such).

I'm using IceWeasel 24.5.0 (FireFox clone for Debian) and, obviously, Debian (wheezy).

Here's the relevant code:

```
public ActivityTextCell() {
    super(BrowserEvents.MOUSEDOWN, BrowserEvents.MOUSEUP);
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(
        com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
        Element parent, 
        ActivityDTO value, 
        NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<ActivityDTO> valueUpdater) {

    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.getType().equals(BrowserEvents.MOUSEUP)) {
        Window.alert("mouse up event");

    }
    else {

        switch ( event.getButton()){
        case NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT:
            Window.alert("right mouseclick");
            break;
        case NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT:
            Window.alert("left mouseclick");
            break;
        case NativeEvent.BUTTON_MIDDLE:
        default:
            break; // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

The class ActivityTextCell extends AbstractCell.

So what am I missing? How do I stop the browser from reaticng to the mouse click?

Answer (score 1):

Well it certainly wasn't a matter of a few minutes (as can be seen by the fact that it has taken me a week to get back to this), but I have a solution. I tried reversing the order of the the `event.preventDefault()` and `super.onBrowserEvent()` but it didn't really help.

I tried a little experiment on a normal web page. It turns out, that the MOUSEDOWN event doesn't do anything in that context and the usual browser selection menu appears on the MOUSEUP. So the if/else logic sort of fell by the wayside.

What did the trick is to include the following in the top level GUI class immediately after adding the main page:

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().addDomHandler(new ContextMenuHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}, ContextMenuEvent.getType());
```

This has the additional benefit (for my purposes, at least) of preventing the Browser from reacting to a right click anywhere in the application view.

As an aside: The purpose of preventing the default action is to stop the Browser doing its own thing Stopping propagation is possibly not required, but I left it in anyway (propagation goes fro the node up to the root, not the other way around). The purpose of overridinging `onBrowserEvent()` is to enable your own application to handel that event. The use of `super.onBrowserEvent()` is to **allow** the event to be handled by your code in the first place. I've given the relevant reference in my previous comment. The book "GWT in Action" is well worth a read if you're likely to be doing a lot of GWT coding.

Answer (score 0):

You call `super.onBrowserEvent()` which triggers the standard browser response.

You should move `event.preventDefault()` to the `if` part of your code, and `super.onBrowserEvent()` to the `else` part. You want one of them executed depending on a browser event, but not both.

Comment: Plus, mouseup is going off while the alert is up, and that's bound to cause a little confusion...

Comment: The use of `super.onBrowserEvent()` and `event.preventDefault()` is something I got from "GWT in Action" (see section 3.6 in  http://www.ouestil.ch/uploads/GWTinAction,SecondEdition.pdf, for an example), so I suspect it can't be wrong. However, I seem to have got them in reverse oder, so I'll try swapping them around. As for the mouseup occurung whilst the pop-up ist displayed... I'll have to think about that a bit. As I said: I'm new to GWT.

Comment: There is no need to suspect anything. You can try my proposed solution in less than a minute and see if it works.